# SASS not compiling (watching) anymore when using serve after Ionic update

Tags: ionic-framework, compilation, sass, gulp

I have recently updated ionic and its libs, but that has changed many things for me.

Right now, I can make some changes in the HTML and my livereload just shows them. When I do this in a certain SCSS file, nothing happens at all. So the `ionic serve --lab` command is just useless for me.

This is my `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});
```

And this is my local environment:

```
Cordova CLI: You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
6.3.1

Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1-nightly-4219
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0-beta.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.6.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
```

Any idea what goes wrong or what I should do? I already tried `ionic setup sass`, but that just works for one time. I do not want to that everytime I change the code. It looks like it's not watching my SCSS file anymore, but I don't know why, because I haven't changed my `gulpfile.js` at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I've found the solution, but it's actually very sad that the transition between ionic 1.x and ionic 2.x is just so badly documentated and not working flawlessly.

Anyway, what I did is:

Add this to my `gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task('serve:before', ['default','watch']);
```

And also change my `ionic.config.js` file to:

```
{
  "name": "HereComesTheNameOfYourApp",
  "app_id": "YOURIDNUMBERHERE",
  "v2": false,
  "typescript": false,
  "watch": {
    "sass": [
      "scss/**/*.scss"
    ],
    "html": [
      "www/**/*.html"
    ],
    "livereload": [
      "www/**/*.html",
      "www/**/*.js",
      "www/**/*.css"
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope it will help someone else as well.

Comment: Thank you @siyah, you saved the day.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug with Ionic, so what you just need to do is running two command prompt:

1. `ionic run serve`
2. `gulp sass`